# How to select a TabItem by its header in a dynamic TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol

I have dynamic `TabControl` with multiple `TabItems`. I need to select a specific `TabItem` based on its header value dynamically. I have found a way to select a `TabItem` by it's index like this,

```
tabControl.SelectedIndex= 0;
```

but in this case I don't know how to find the index of that `TabItem` by its header.

My pseudo-code is something like that:

```
if(tabControl.Contains(myHeader))
{
   tabControl.SelectedItem = myHeader;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your tab content is a type `TabContent` with a property `Header` and you bind your items via the `ItemsSource` property, you can do this.

```
tabControl.SelectedItem = TabControl.Items.OfType<TabContent>().SingleOrDefault(ti => ti.Header.Equals(myHeader));
```

If you directly assign `TabItem`s to your `TabControl`, you can do this.

```
tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(ti => ti.Header.Equals(myHeader));
```

Since both examples use Linq for convenience, be sure to import it with `using System.Linq;`. The `OfType<T>()` method will filter the items for a specific type and `SingleOrDefault()` will return a single element that matches the criteria or `null`, which would mean that no tab item is selected.